# show custom post's post in two different divs

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, query-posts, get-posts

I have created a custom post type. For that I have used this code

```
add_action( 'init', 'broker_post_type' );
function broker_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'new_broker',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Brands' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Brand' )
      ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
    )
  );
}
```

Now to show all the featured image of the post type Brands in a single page I have used this code

```
function display_broker_posts() {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'new_broker',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
  );

  $dee_bios = new WP_Query( $args );
  if( $dee_bios->have_posts() ):
    $dee_output = '<div id="brokers-wrap">';
    $dee_output .= '<div id="brokers-bg-wrap">';
    $dee_output .= '<div class="brokers-content">';
    $dee_output .= '<div class="brokers-left-content">';
    while ( $dee_bios->have_posts() ) : $dee_bios->the_post();
      if( $dee_bios->current_post == 0 || ( $dee_bios->current_post % 2 ) == 0 ) {
        $dee_output .= '<div class="one-half first">';
        }
      else {
        $dee_output .= '<div class="one-half">';
        }

      $dee_output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $dee_bios->post->ID,'small', 'bios', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) );
      $dee_output .= '<span></span>';
    //  $dee_output .= '<p><strong>' . get_the_title() . ',</strong> ' . get_the_content() . '</p>';
      $dee_output .= '</div><!--end .one-half-->';
    endwhile;
    $dee_output .= '<div class="clear"></div><!--clear all floats-->';
    $dee_output .= '</div><!-- end #bios-->';
  endif;

  wp_reset_postdata();
  return $dee_output;
}
```

Now this one is giving the result. But here in result I want something different. I want that lets say I have `16 posts in the Post`. So it will show `first 10 posts in a different div and the rest 6 posts in a different div`. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: How the logic you want is related to wordpress? Don't you think this is just to do with PHP?

Comment: @Chittaranjan .. Can yo help me in this?

Comment: Can you please clean up your code? I do not see where the `a` tag ends.

Comment: @Chittaranjan I have updated my code.. Can you check it now?

Answer (score 0):

Just before the `while` loop starts, have a counter variable like

```
$counter = 0;
```

Just before the `endwhile`, add the following check with counter.

```
if ( ++$counter == 10 )
{
    $dee_output .= '</div><div class="second-half">';
}
```

**Note:** I don't see correct number of opening and closing `div` tags, so please check your code.